# Ubuntu fails to detect NVMe SSD in T14s Ryzen laptop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lenovo, nvme

Since yesterday I've been trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 from a USB stick (dualboot with Windows 10) onto my Lenovo Thinkpad T14s Gen 1 laptop bought from China.

The issue being: Ubuntu, along with Manjaro and gparted live CDs, consistently fails to detect my internal NVMe SSD. This seems to be a general Linux issue. More specifically, the NVMe and AHCI controllers are detected by the kernel as PCI devices (according to lspci), but an error occurs during the initialization of the NVMe controller ("`unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 56`"). The disk device itself is not listed in lsblk, gparted, Disks or any other utility, and so installation cannot proceed.

Both Fast Startup and Secure Boot are off, and the laptop appears to already be in AHCI mode as Windows lists the AHCI controller in Device Manager (there's no option for it in the BIOS). The drive works on Windows without any issue, while Linux seems to be very insistent on refusing to work with it.

System specs:

- **CPU/GPU**: AMD Ryzen Pro 7 4750U with Radeon Graphics
- **SSD**:

  - A Lenovo OEM PM981a drive
  - Exact model: `SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7` (1 TB)
  - Firmware version: `5M2QEXF7` (as I checked, there don't seem to be any updates provided either by Lenovo or Samsung for this drive)
- **UEFI BIOS Version**: "`R1CET23W(0.23 )`" (March 6th 2020)

Samsung Magician doesn't seem to suggest any new firmware for the drive. Moreover, my laptop was sent into a BSoD loop upon installing this utility, so I deleted it and it has booted fine into Windows ever since.

I can't seem to find any BIOS update options on Lenovo's website, as it fails to find any product matching my laptop's serial number, and I'm not sure which firmware to choose manually for a hypothetical update. I've also noticed that the label on the bottom of my laptop says "T490s" while the front label says "T14s", meaning the laptop is potentially reassembled from parts (?).

Relevant kernel logs:

```
[    1.260571] ahci 0000:08:00.0: version 3.0
[    1.263048] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.0: SDHCI controller found [17a0:9750] (rev 1)
[    1.263055] nvme 0000:01:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
[    1.267015] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:01:00.0
[    1.273158] ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 56
[    1.273162] fbcon: Taking over console
[    1.273167] nvme 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A: failed to register GSI
[    1.276198] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.279314] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    1.279314] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    1.279661] ahci 0000:08:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    1.279668] ahci 0000:08:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    1.282980] nvme: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12
[    1.283368] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.283764] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfd001000 port 0xfd001100 irq 80
[    1.284189] ahci 0000:08:00.1: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    1.284192] ahci 0000:08:00.1: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    1.284363] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.284397] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfd000000 port 0xfd000100 irq 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply booting the kernel with the "noapic" option appears to resolve the issue for me!

I'm not sure if this solution is going to be permanent or temporary, but at least the drive is seen by Linux now.

If anyone has better insight into the root of the issue, or any potential problems with my fix, feel free to comment on that.